# Mongoid has_many relation returning fake data when enumerated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I will give a quick background. I am building a directed graph in Rails with the following (summarized) models:

```
Node
has_many :edges, foreign_key: "source_id"
```

and

```
Edge
field :source_id, :type => String
field :destination_id, :type => String
belongs_to :source, class_name: "Node"
belongs_to :destination, class_name: "Node"
```

I have come across 2 bizarre issues with Mongoid has_many and belongs_to relationship. The results of the relational query seem to vary depending on what method I use to retrieve the `Node` object.

**First**, calling `to_a` on the relation (as well as enumerating over the relation, i.e. `each`, `map`, `collect`) causes an extra `Edge` to be retrieved, as seen below where the count returns as 31.

**Second**, the issue with the extra `Edge` only seems to occur when the query that retrieves the `Node` is different than a straight forward `find`. But as you can see, according to Rails `node1` is equal to `node2`.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can shed any light on these issues. Let me know if additional information would be helpful.

```
1.9.3-p327 :145 > node1 = some_other_node.neighbors.select {|n| n[:node].city == "983"}.first[:node]
 => #<Node _id: 54da32b1756275343ed70300, city: "983"> 

1.9.3-p327 :140 > node2 = Node.find_by(:city => "983")
 => #<Node _id: 54da32b1756275343ed70300, city: "983"> 

1.9.3-p327 :141 > node1 == node2
 => true 

1.9.3-p327 :150 > node1.edges.count
 => 30 
1.9.3-p327 :151 > node1.edges.to_a.count
 => 31 
1.9.3-p327 :152 > node2.edges.count
 => 30 
1.9.3-p327 :153 > node2.edges.to_a.count
 => 30
```

**EDIT** Providing information about the extra edge.

The extra `Edge` that is returned should **absolutely not** be returned. You can see below that the extra `Edge` has a `source` that is **not equal** to `node1`. Every other `Edge` that is returned has `node1` as the source, which is precisely what I expect based on the relationship.

```
1.9.3-p327 :167 >   node1.edges.to_a.last.source
 => #<Node _id: 54da32b0756275343e000000, city: "0">
```

Here is more evidence to support my claim. Notice that all of `node2` edges have `node2` as the `source`, but this is not true for `node1`.

```
1.9.3-p327 :170 > node2.edges.to_a.collect {|e| e.source == node2}.include? false
 => false 
1.9.3-p327 :171 > node1.edges.to_a.collect {|e| e.source == node1}.include? false
 => true
```

However, it is peculiar that the extra `Edge` would have `city: "0"` as the source because in the initial assignment of `node1` the `some_other_node` is `city: "0"`. That does not seem like a coincidence.

Comment: Have you checked to see what the extra element in `node1.edges.to_a` looks like?

Comment: Yes I have, see updated answer for additional information about the extra edge.

Comment: Shouldn't your Node `has_many :in_edges` and `has_many :out_edges`?

Comment: Not necessarily, to be complete I would say yes, but for functionality I only need to be able to retrieve the `out_edges`.

Comment: I'm wondering about ["Definitions are required on both sides to the relation in order for it to work properly, unless one of the models is embedded."](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many).

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort for the suggestion, issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved! Thanks for the suggestion mu is too short. When I attempted to implement both `out_edges` and `in_edges` on the `Node` I discovered that Mongoid was complaining about the inverse relation being ambiguous. Interestingly, it was happily silent when I was only defining the `out_edges`.

Just to clarify, It is **not** required to define both `out_edges` and `in_edges`, I was able to make the defect go away by including the `inverse_of` definitions in the `Edge` model.

```
Node
    has_many :edges, foreign_key: "source_id"

Edge
    field :source_id, :type => String
    field :destination_id, :type => String
    belongs_to :source, inverse_of: "edges", class_name: "Node"
    belongs_to :destination, inverse_of: "in_edges", class_name: "Node"
```

EDIT

Rails/Mongoid do not appear to care that `destination` is defined with `inverse_of: "in_edges"` even though `in_edges` does not exist in Node. But if I remove that part then the issue returns. Mongoid definitely has some defects here.

Comment: Yeah, I've found that the non-embedded relations in Mongoid behave strangely sometimes. Sometimes you need to have both `has_many` and `belongs_to` set up, sometimes you don't; sometimes you need `:inverse_of`, sometimes you don't.